# PCRE tag merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

Today I tried to see recent questions under [pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre) tag, I saw a redirection to [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag page. I wasn't aware about merged tags but when read about it wondered if this is a case for merging these two tags since [pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre) is a regex flavor, [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) would be the specific syntax that PCRE provides besides its general definition.

Comment: Looks like a synonym suggestion was submitted on Jan 11th by [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) and that got enough votes I guess to be executed automatically.

Comment: Is this suggestion visible to take a look?

Comment: Great, I was doing a search with `[PCRE]` as part of my keyword to filter out results. I got only results with [tag:regex] tag. That has confused me. I do not see why this is accepted as synonym...

Comment: Fun part is that the [regex wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) still mentions the [tag:pcre] tag as *a commonly used open source C library inspired by Perl's regular expressions*. It doesn't consider it to be a synonym at all ...

Comment: @revo yes, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest) filter on *pcre*

Comment: No, it hasn't been merged. If the synonym is reverted, everything will be going back to how it was (unless the "Renames" number goes up, in which case there would be questions that meant to use the pcre tag but got renamed)

Comment: This sort of thing happening is one of the reasons we need synonym suggestions/voting to be more discoverable, so that people who are regularly active in a tag see that there is a synonym that's been proposed and can vote on it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**This should be reverted.** The [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) has this important instruction:

> "Always two there are; no more, no less. A master and an apprentice."

Oh, sorry, this one:

> Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

We always ask people **not to use the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag alone**, but to add their flavor or programming language as another tag.
The tag [pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre) is particularly useful - PCRE has many unique features that do not apply to other flavors.
Also, when someone knows what [pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre) is, they are probably asking a relatively interesting regex question.

Comment: Agreed... so how do we do that?

Comment: I've flagged this question and asked for a moderator help. I don't think other users can undo a synonym.

Comment: I've removed the synonym - might take a little bit to show properly - caching and all that.

Comment: wow, I actually could down vote that synonym request.Where did my life go wrong?

Comment: @rene done. You can follow the discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367896) - removed previous comments as well.