# Regex tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonym-process

Recently, I proposed the synonym [pcre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre) for [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex). This synonym was eventually voted in and `pcre` questions became `regex` questions. The problem is that not everyone thought this was a great idea, and since I've read [this meta post about the synonym I created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366139/), **I completely agree**. My proposed synonym was eventually reverted.

After the initial tag confusion (and eventual tag synonym removal) two further problems arose:

1. I was never notified that the tag synonym was deleted and, as such, I thought it was weird when I searched for `pcre` tagged questions and it didn't automatically change it to the `regex` tag. I shrugged my shoulders and recreated the synonym suggestion anew as I thought I may have either been dreaming or it was a bug or something, who knows!?

   - My point here is that it would be a good idea to have some sort of system in place to prevent or influence a user to not recreate the tag synonym. Some suggestions might be to (or even combine the following):

     1. Notify the person that suggested the tag synonym that their suggestion was removed (and potentially provide context). This would have prevented me from creating the tag suggestion a second time around.
     2. Flag such synonyms after removal (from the moderator side) so that moderators can promptly remove *flagged* tag synonyms before they go any further.
     3. Provide users that are about to propose a particular (flagged) tag synonym suggestion with a prompt indicating them that the synonym *is not a good idea* and maybe providing further context as to *why* that may be (getting back to point 1).
2. The `regex` tag synonyms cause quite a bit of confusion. In the [meta post about the synonym I created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366139/), it is specified that:

   > We always ask people not to use the regex tag alone, but to add their
   >   flavor or programming language as another tag.

   At the same time, however, a second meta post, [*Split the [regex] tag?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317596/), discusses splitting the `regex` tag into smaller tags. The problem here, is that this has also been implemented and, currently, Stack Overflow's [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag contains the following synonyms: [regex-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-php) [perl-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-regex) [perlre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perlre) [apache-regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-regexp). Had the `regex` tag not included these other tags that help to specify the flavour, I would not have suggested `pcre` as a synonym in the first place.

#### Questions

- Why is there this sort of *double-standard* regarding tag synonyms for the `regex` tag: I mean, if `pcre` should not be a synonym of `regex`, should the same not also apply to the aforementioned tag synonyms?

Comment: On the second question: the tag combinations those passages allude to presumably not \[regex\]\[regex-php\] and \[regex\]\[regex-perl\], but rather \[regex\]\[php\] and \[regex\]\[perl\]. The \[regex\]\[pcre\] combination is similar, with \[pcre\] narrowing the scope, be it used in the PCRE-the-library sense or in the PCRE-the-regex-flavour one.

Comment: @duplode but if the tag `[regex-php]` is meant to allude to `[regex][php]`, the user should do exactly that and specify both tags. The `[regex-php]` tag seems useless and confusing to me if anything.

Comment: Yup -- [regex][php] is useful; [regex][regex-php] is not. As I see it, [regex][pcre] is more like [regex][php] than [regex][regex-php], and so [pcre] should exist as a separate tag, unlike [regex-php].

Comment: @duplode if that's the case, then shouldn't the tags [tag:perlre], [tag:regex-php], [tag:perl-regex], [tag:apache-regexp] be burninated to prevent confusion?

Comment: "shouldn't the tags perlre, regex-php, perl-regex, apache-regexp be burninated?" -- They are already synonyms, and so, as far as I understand, they are not subject to burnination.

Comment: Just FYI, synonyms are poorly handled in general. Synonym proposals never notify tag users they're there to be voted on. So getting notified of a mod removing them (a rare occurrence) would actually be different. And there was a Meta post so you could figure out what happened. I agree a notice would be better but [there's more important notices we still don't have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned/351409#351409)

Comment: Given that the flavour of regex in PHP is PCRE now that ereg has been deprecated and removed, I find the existence of both [tag:regex-php] and [tag:perl-regex] to be confusing at best

Comment: @Scoots and ctwheels : The proper thing to ask for in the case of those synonyms, as I have just learned, is a [tag merger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/242059). (I believe the one practical effect of note of that would be that \[regex\] wouldn't show up in the autocompletion suggestions for e.g. \[perl\] anymore.)