# Create synonym for vuetify

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Recently, somebody created [vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuetify) tag. Thus far, [vuetify.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuetify.js) tag has been used. However, atm they are not synonyms for some reason.

Somebody with sufficient rep, please fix it because they are the same thing.

See [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/synonyms) I think something similar should be done with [vuetify.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuetify.js).

Comment: Just retag those 15 questions to the older tag.

Comment: @Braiam but then what about future tagging? I think it's better to create a synonym now.

Comment: I've pinged the user who created the vuetify tag to learn if that was intentional or not. If intentional, a synonym could be in order, if not, retagging those 15 questions is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: @rene Thank you. I wonder how to prevent it in the future then? Isn't it still best thing to just create synonyms as in case of [tag:vue.js] as I had noted? I'm saying someone in the future might apparently create the tag again, then will we have to retag again? What's the downside of creating a synonym in the first place?

Comment: You need 1500 rep to create a tag and you are shown a popup when you are about to create a tag. I assume most tag creation is prevented right there. If it keeps re-appearing it is early enough to create the synonym. The only down side is that you need users to vote on the synonym. And someone need to get it started. [Which could be you](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vuetify.js/synonyms) as you have enough rep in that tag. Then the meta post can be used as advertisement to attract synonym voters. But if that doesn't workout a mod needs to do it.

Comment: While there is no imminent down side, in the future, history can haunt you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367969/can-we-repurpose-the-jade-tag-for-the-jade-community or the wrong tags get synomized: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366139/pcre-tag-merged (that last one got proposed as synonym again later on)

Comment: @rene I want to stress out that I actually can't do it (start a synonym proposal), because I need 2500 overall reputation, hence this post. Thank you for clarification, and pointing out possible downsides. I wonder why the user who started typing `vuet` didn't notice vuetify.js? Or perhaps they noticed but ignored for some reason? And also why was it approved - by other users -  as a tag then, if we already have one? When prompted, tag contained no description whatsoever, so clearly there is a flaw somewhere in the process. Perhaps in the reward system?

Comment: Oh I missed the rep limit that applied, sorry for that. They might have seen it when they typed, or not, when they were on mobile or their internet blipped when the ajax call was supposed to return tag suggestions. No other users need to approve tag creation. If you have the rep, you're good to go. Tag creation doesn't get reviewed (at least not by means of review queue)

Comment: I asked if a [tag creation monitoring bot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43142452#43142452) exists in SOBotics but it looks we don't have one yet

Comment: @rene Oh, I see. Still after considering the possibilities and eventual outcomes, it appears to me that having suggested synonym wont hurt. Because afaiu even if something else pops up in the future called `vuetify` (I guess unlikely to happen tho) we can just remove the synonym and create it as separate tag because questions will have former tag in the first place.

Comment: vuetify has been merged and syn'd to vuetify.js.

Comment: @rene it's not a queue but users with access to the 10k tools can see newly created tags at https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats - I just imagine most people don't know about it or have just forgotten about it though...

Comment: @JonClements last time I checked that page was more then 6 to 8 somethings ago ...